# unit testing of class without dependencies

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Imagine I have the following class:

```
public class MyWeirdCollection
{
    private IList<string> _myTrueList;
    private IList<string> _myFalseList;

    public MyCollection()
    {
        _myTrueList = new List<string>();
        _myFalseList = new List<string>();
    }

    public void Add(string item, bool listType)
    {
        if (listType)
        {
            _myTrueList.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            _myFalseList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    public IList<string> Get(bool listType)
    {
        return listType ? _myTrueList : myFalseList;
    }
}
```

How would I go about unit testing the `Get` and `Add` methods? I'm doubting between 2 possible solutions:

1. Making the 2 lists protected instead of private, so I can create an inheriting `TestableWeirdCollectionClass` that exposes the content of the lists to the test
2. Leave the class as it is and test `Add` and `Get` together? i.e. calling `Add` to add some elements and then `Get` to see if the correct values come back.

I'm leaning towards option no. 2, but would like some more opinions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely go for the option 2. Pretty much every test I can imagine **must** go though `Add`, then `Get`, together.

When testing you are ultimately testing the public interface, not the internal state. The whole idea of the test code is that you give items to it, then you get them back with the appropriate key. In your particular case it uses private lists to hold the items, but this may not be the case (you might store them to a database or file, rely on another class or something else). This is ultimately an implementation detail, the important bit is that `Add` and `Get` always play together, therefore you should it.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend option 2. The reason is that your whole class should be consider a unit, and be tested as such. Making methods public for the sole purpose of unit testing can be motivated in some rare cases for very complex classes, but should be avoided if at all possible.

See also

- [Is it bad practice to make methods public solely for the sake of unit testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274937/is-it-bad-practice-to-make-methods-public-solely-for-the-sake-of-unit-testing).
- [Would you rather make private stuff internal/public for tests, or use some kind of hack like PrivateObject](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126545/would-you-rather-make-private-stuff-internal-public-for-tests-or-use-some-kind)